# Textbox value gets removed on postback

Tags: javascript

I have two textbox A and B. Textbox A takes the same value of textbox B using javascript, but on postback Textbox B value is becoming null but textbox A remains the same.I want to see both the textbox values on postback.What can i do. Here is my javascript code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function myFunction() 
    {
       document.getElementById('<%=txtCloseQuantity.ClientID %>').value =
       document.getElementById('<%=txtOpenQty.ClientID %>').value;                          
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use javascript for this?

Comment: Why don't you store your value in ViewState["TextBoxValue"], so you can retrieve after post back